# El registro de transacciones de la base de datos está lleno

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un problema cuando intento borrar algunos datos en mi base de datos, cuando hago un delete sql server me manda el siguiente mensaje:

`El registro de transacciones de la base de datos 'Finprue' está lleno. Para saber por qué no se puede volver a utilizar el espacio del registro, vea la columna log_reuse_wait_desc de sys.databases`

ahora, encontré un código que decía ayudaba a reducir el log de la base de datos y todo funcionaria bien, pero ya lo probé y me dice que el log no existe, aquí les dejo dicho código y salida:

```
use Finprue
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Finprue_Log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
USE [Finprue]
go
ALTER DATABASE Finprue
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (Finprue_Log, 80);
GO
ALTER DATABASE basededatos
SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

`Mens. 8985, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 2
No se encontró el archivo 'Finprue_Log' para la base de datos 'Finprue' en sys.database_files. No existe el archivo o se quitó.`

Alguien sabrá alguna forma alterna para solucionar este problema? 
Les agradezco sus comentarios, buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, al parecer no tenía suficiente espacio en el DD de mi servidor, al liberar unos 15gb pude hacer operaciones con la base de datos, queda como precedente como una posible solución por si alguien tiene un problema similar!

Comment: En ese caso, procede a marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia a "simple" el modo de recuperación de la Base de datos, luego ejecuta

```
use Finprue
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Finprue_Log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
```

Y finalmente vuelve a poner la base de datos en modo de recuperación "Full"